# Override client_side_validations behavior to validate hidden fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, client-side-validation

I am using the [client_side_validations](https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations) gem with Rails 3.1.0.  I have been trying to use it to validate a hidden field that is set through a javascript widget. From what I have read on the gem's github page, the gem deliberately does not validate hidden fields because the user could not correct these fields.  I have unsuccessfully tried to override this behavior.

Is there a way to override this behavior for a particular field without modifying the client_side_validations code (other than the init stuff that gets generated when you install the gem)?.

The way I've done it now is by making a slight modification to the validateForm function in the gem. When it looks for the fields to validate it only grabs the elements that are visible:

```
form.find(':input:enabled:visible[data-validate]').each(function()
```

So I changed that to this:

```
form.find(':input:enabled[data-validate]').each(function()
```

This seems to work.  Is there a better way?

I haven't been able to re-validate the hidden field when the user corrects their mistakes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to validate hidden fields that is how to do it

Comment: Thanks for your answer. One issue I have run into with my solution is that the hidden field does not get revalidated when I use my widget.  I have tried using focus() and blur() on the hidden element in the widget's click event but can't seem to get the field to revalidate. What event do I need to trigger to make this happen? Any suggestions?

Comment: @jmeas I am the author of ClientSideValidations and I am offering the definitive answer that "this is how you do it"

Comment: @mushroom I am cannot offer help if you decide to customize the ClientSideValidation code as you have suggested. CSV does not validate against hidden fields for good reasons. I highly suggest you do not do this, but if you absolutely need to your method is the way.

Comment: Accidentally up-voted the first comment... I will probably avoid modifying the code as it has already created other issues that I would need to find workarounds for.  Probably can't use the gem for this particular situation.  Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: @mushroom Hidden fields don't respond to focus or blur.  See the workarounds suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18010412/focus-cursor-to-a-hidden-field), which would probably address your CSV issue too.

Answer (score 1):

@mushroom asked about client_side_validations version 3.1, but for anyone using version 3.2.x, this is now configurable.

[This code](https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations/blob/3-2-stable/coffeescript/rails.validations.coffee#L111) on 3.2-stable branch shows how it's done.

You will need to override `window.ClientSideValidations.selectors.validate_inputs` and `window.ClientSideValidations.selectors.inputs` once the page loads.  As for including validations for the hidden element in the hash, my recommendation is to load the page with the element visible, and immediately run `$('#id_of_hidden_element').attr('type', 'hidden')`.

Alternatively, you can just make the input element `type='text'` and use `opacity:0` in a CSS stylesheet to make it invisible.  Note that this has other side-effects, such as making it focusable.

Answer (score 0):

I think better way is validate it by adding 'id' or 'class'

`<input type="hidden" id="validate_me">`

then selector should be like this:

`':input:enabled:visible[data-validate], #validate_me'`