# rails v3 with select2 gem ignoring client_side_validation error message

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, client-side-validation, jquery-select2

I'm using rails 3.0.9, client_side_validation gem and just tried to use select2 gem by using thier js and css file manually

Downloaded the files from https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/tags

A simple form with a presence validation

```
    <%= javascript "validations/rails.live.validations", "select2.min"%>
    <%= stylesheet "select2"%>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#user_tag_ids").select2();
             });
    </script>
    <%= form_for @user, :validate => true do |f| %>
        <%= f.label :tag_ids %><%= mark_required(@user, :tag_ids) %>
        <%= f.collection_select(:tag_ids, @hobbies, :id, :display_name, {:prompt => "please select"}, :multiple => true) %>
        <%= f.submit %>
    <% end %>
```

Now the select box *UI* changed as expected,

But when the cursor is focused out without selecting any value, then client_side_validation gem should display a error message but no message is displayed (not even the error_field class is set to that fields).

Does select2 gem ignores/skiping to render the error message ?

If I click submit button then only i'm getting (client_side_validation gem) error message.

Any idea to solve this?

Comment: Your issue might be related with this answer here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14186916/override-client-side-validations-behavior-to-validate-hidden-fields][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14186916/override-client-side-validations-behavior-to-validate-hidden-fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add validation to the current settings object in javascript. Example

```
var validators = window[$('#place_order_form').attr('id')].validators

var input_name = $("#user_tag_ids").attr('name');
validators[input_name] = {"presence":{"message":"Must be filled"}}
```

Reference: https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations/issues/149

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I tried the solution I sent you in the comment, but turned out I had to do this:

In rails.validations.js file, instead of

```
 form.find(':input:enabled:visible[data-validate]').each(function() {
```

try:

```
 form.find(':input[data-validate]').each(function() {
```

Comment: Yes, But it may affect my other forms also and i think no need a big change in js file for checking presence for a field

Comment: The :input selector takes all form elements. If you are only having trouble with the select tag, which is hidden because the select2 hides the real select tag with display:none, you might try with form.find(':input:enabled:visible[data-validate], select:hidden[data-validate]') or you can manually do the validation in seperate js file.