# Focus cursor to a hidden field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this script where i want cursor to be focused on hidden field but it doesn't seem to be working . When i make the field visible it seems to work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#card_number").focus();
    $("#card_number").keypress(function() {
       alert($("#card_number").val());
    });
});
```

Comment: Hidden inputs cannot have focus, they are *hidden*. If you mean you used CSS to set the visibility, please show the corresponding CSS.

Comment: Do you mean 'hidden' as in `<input type="hidden" />` or as in `<input type="text" style="visiblity: hidden;" />`?

Comment: Hidden inputs can't gain focus nor even other UI events as they remain hidden or don't occupy any space in view. Focusing inputs fields that are kept hidden from users don't make any sense.

Comment: i even tried with CSS its the same

Answer (score 8):

You can't focus on a hidden element.

You can use `opacity: 0` instead of `display: none` and you will be able to focus on the element.

Comment: That's exactly what the answer says? display: none means that the element is hidden @SteveHorvath

Comment: Something to be cognizant of with this solution that `display: none;` will NOT allocate space in the DOM for the element, whereas while simply setting the opacity as indicated may render the element invisible, it will _still_ allocate space in the DOM.

Answer (score 4):

i found the solutions by trying out your comments , you can't use visibility: hidden; . You have to use opacity zero

```
#card_number{

    opacity: 0;
}
```

Thanks fellas you were great This is for an auto login feature

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know this isn't possible for a hidden field. What you might want to do is set the opacity of the input field to 0 via CSS.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to do this same thing to use with a scanning device without the user seeing the numbers flying in.

I tried `Opcacity:0` but when it has focus you see the text cursor blinking which is not optimal.

What I did, that works neatly is: `{position: fixed; left: 300em}`

Answer (score 1):

The reason is the field is hidden.

Don't hide the field just try to make the opacity to 0% using CSS

Answer (score 0):

Focus function is not work with hidden fields. Make the opacity to zero

Answer (score -1):

You cant focus on any hidden field. What are you trying to achieve here.